# Collision of nested typenames in MSVC

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, types

I have encountered a problem while was using variadic templates, but the problem is not related to variadic templates and can be reproduced without them.
The problem is related to same names of types in inherited and base classes.

I've simplified code to the following snippet:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int member;
};

struct B: public A
{
    typedef A NEXT;

    short member;
};

struct Foo: public B
{
    typedef B NEXT;

    void Check()
    { 
        std::cout << typeid(NEXT::member).name() << '\n';
        std::cout << typeid(NEXT::NEXT::member).name() << '\n';

        NEXT::NEXT::member = 1;
        NEXT::member = 2;

        std::cout << NEXT::NEXT::member << '\n';
        std::cout << NEXT::member << '\n';
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.Check();
}
```

It compiles without warnings and works with GCC and clang, but it produces wrong output with MSVC (at least with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1).

It seems that some collision in names happens, and it treats `NEXT::NEXT::member` as `NEXT::member`, but in the same place, it lies to `typeid` (as well as to `std::is_same`).

When compiled with GCC or clang the output is:

```
s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
i                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
2
```

But in case of MSVC, the output is:

```
short
int
2
2
```

The following code compiles without warnings with GCC or clang, but as expected produces error with MSVC:

```
struct A
{
    int member;
};

struct B: public A
{
    typedef A NEXT;

    short member;
};

struct Foo: public B
{
    typedef B NEXT;

    short& GetB() { return NEXT::member; };
    int& GetA()   { return NEXT::NEXT::member; };    
};
```

The MSVC error:

```
source_file.cpp(18): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'short' to 'int &'
```

Is the code above valid? Is it a problem of MSVC or I'm utilizing UB somehow?

## Update

The problem can not be reproduced in MSVC 2015 update 3.

Comment: Which Update of MSVC are you using?

Comment: @Rakete1111 At the moment I'm using 14.0.24720, that is update 1. But the problem appeared initially with variadic templates with MSVC update 3. I'm almost positive that the same behavior will be reproduced in update 3.

Comment: That's why I wanted to know, because I *can't* reproduce both of your problems with update 3 :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: so it is very likely a bug in the earlier builds of MSVC?

Comment: I've checked, the problem initially happened with MSVC update 2.
There is no problem with update 3.
So it seems like a bug in earlier versions of MSVC.

Comment: It's clearly a bug. Good work nailing it down! :) You can report compiler bugs at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).